# Dismissing a Dismissible with Flutter/Dart

Tags: dart, flutter

In the majority of the [Dismissible](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Dismissible-class.html) examples provided by Flutter, they are dismissing items within a ListView. For example, [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/80b820a26d78a0c8d0e3c8ddf7dbb996c9a1548b/dev/manual_tests/lib/card_collection.dart).

What I am currently doing is this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Scaffold(
    key: _scaffoldKey,
    appBar: new AppBar(
      title: new Text(widget.title),
    ),
    body: new Center(
      child: new ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Dismissible(
            key: personKey,
            child: new Text('Dismiss Me'),
            onDismissed: (DismissDirection direction) {}
          )
        ],
      ) // end ListView
    ) // end Center
  ); // end return
} // end build()
```

After I dismiss the text box, I get the error:

> A dismissed Dismissible widget is still part of the tree.
>
> Make sure to implement the onDismissed handler and to immediately remove the Dismissible widget from the application once that handler has fired.

Digging through the Dismissible [source](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/dismissible.dart) at , I see that it checks that status of `_resizeAnimation`, but I'm not sure how that fits into the grand scheme of a `Dismissible` constructor or `onDismissed` handler.

Comment: This question was useful to me, since it showed me where I needed to add the onDismissed handler to the Dismissible. Pretty obvious, but I still struggled because I'm pretty new to Flutter.

Answer (score 125):

Please try this.I provided UniqueKey as key to Dismissible widget, and it worked just fine.

```
key: UniqueKey(),
```

Comment: you can just call `key: UniqueKey()` instead of  key: `Key(UniqueKey().toString())`

Comment: 2 RoyalGriffin
from here https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/gestures/dismissible
  // Each Dismissible must contain a Key. Keys allow Flutter to
  // uniquely identify widgets.
  key: Key(item),

Answer (score 21):

Make sure the values you're passing to the `key` parameters are unique as well. And DO NOT use the index of an item. Since after removing an item from an array, the array will shift the positions of the items, the `Dismissable` widget will not recognize the removal of an item.

Comment: Great one, thanks! I've used index as a part of key as well, didn't realize it would remain and cause the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , It helped me , Thanks, I used the index , and cause me the Error

Answer (score 13):

The error comes when the widget is dismissed but not removed from the tree since the state still contains the dismissed object. Ideal implementation for onDismissed should remove the item and set the new state

So in your example you would do something like this

```
onDismissed: (DismissDirection direction) { dismissPerson(person); }
```

and in dismissPerson function remove the person and set new state.

```
dismissPerson(person) {
    if (_personList.contains(person)) {
    //_personList is list of person shown in ListView
      setState(() {
        _personList.remove(person);
      });
    }
}
```

If you refer to the same [link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/80b820a26d78a0c8d0e3c8ddf7dbb996c9a1548b/dev/manual_tests/lib/card_collection.dart) posted in the question it now contains proper implementation for dismissible. Adding the relevant snippet of code from the link for convenience

```
final Widget card = new Dismissible(
      key: new ObjectKey(cardModel),
      direction: _dismissDirection,
      onDismissed: (DismissDirection direction) { dismissCard(cardModel); },

      ....

    );


void dismissCard(CardModel card) {
    if (_cardModels.contains(card)) {
      setState(() {
        _cardModels.remove(card);
      });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

simplest way
1-> set unique id for each item of list with

```
var uuid = new Uuid();

  new MyItem(title: "Sanjay Singh Bisht",color:"#123ab",uniqueId:uuid.v1()));
```

as mentioned in above post  Dismissible widget required unique id

2-> now to delete item its simple

```
if (items.contains(deletedItem)) {
    setState(() {
      items.remove(deletedItem);
    });
  }
```

3- to undo delete item just update that item id so that Dismissible widget has unique id always

```
setState(() {
deletedItem.uniqueId=uuid.v1();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty clear.

> Make sure to implement the onDismissed handler and to **immediately remove the Dismissible widget from the application** once that handler has fired.

An empty function is not enough. Once an item has been dismissed, that widget has to be removed from the widget tree. Which means that you **must** remove the `Dismissible` from your `ListView`.

Comment: That is clearly what the error message says. In this specific case, the Dimissible is not part of a ListView. I did not find a way to remove a widget that wasn't part of a ListView.

Comment: In the code you provided, `Dismissible` _is_ part of a `ListView`

Comment: The message might be clear, but it's not clear how you **immediately remove the Dismissible widget from the application**

Comment: @LukePighetti Make a setState that will rerender without the dismissible

Answer (score 0):

Be careful if you use some kind of ListView you have to put the UniqueKey in that list, the dismissible also has another key.

```dart
body: ReorderableListView.builder(
  key: UniqueKey(),  //important when deleting Dismissible
  itemCount: db.toDoList.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Dismissible(
      key: **Key**('$index'
    ),
  }
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

A dismissed Dismissible widget is still part of the tree. Make sure to implement the `onDismissed` handler and to immediately remove the Dismissible widget from the application once that handler has fired. See also: https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/errors