# How to handle item keys when implementing swipe to dismiss

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to create a list where you can swipe to dismiss items. The issue is if I add a few items, remove one, and add a new item, I get an error where "a dismissed dismissible widget is still a part of the tree". I'm assuming this is an issue with the keys of my items. Does flutter handle the reorganization of the item keys when I dismiss objects, which means there is simply an error in my code, or should I construct my own custom object that has it's own custom keys. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Variables:**

```
List<String> goals = [];
final TextEditingController listCtrl = new TextEditingController();
```

**Textfield / Adding Items**:

```
TextFormField(
   controller: listCtrl, 
),

RaisedButton(
   child: Text("ADD"),
   onPressed: (){
      goals.add(listCtrl.text);
      listCtrl.clear();
      Navigator.pop(context);
   }, 
)
```

**ListView Builder:**

```
ListView.builder(
          itemCount: goals.length,
          itemBuilder: (context,index){
            final goal = goals[index];
            return Dismissible(
```

**Swipe-to-Dismiss Code:**

```
return Dismissible(
 key: Key(goal),
 onDismissed:(direction){
    if(goals.contains(index)){
       setState((){
          goals.removeAt(index);
       });
    }
 },
)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dismissing a Dismissible with Flutter/Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47735143/dismissing-a-dismissible-with-flutter-dart)

Comment: Thank you it does, it suggests not to use an index as a key when dismissing (which I'm doing which I'm guessing is the issue). What should I use instead?

Comment: Do your items have unique ids or other keys? If not, the linked question suggests using `UniqueKey()` for the key.

Comment: For some reason the error persists when I use UniqueKey() so I'm going to try creating an object that gives them each a key