# How do I get rid of the onDismissible handler error?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am trying to use Dismissible() to delete one of the transactions from the transaction list and the app screen. But I am getting the error

> A dismissed Dismissible widget is still part of the tree.
>
> Make sure to implement the onDismissed handler and to immediately remove the Dismissible widget from the application once that handler has fired.

I checked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47735143/dismissing-a-dismissible-with-flutter-dart) where someone suggested changing the `key: Key()` to a `UniqueKey()` from indexing- which I did as my transactions have an id- but still, I am getting the error mentioned above.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
class TransactionList extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Transaction> transactions;
  final Function deleteTx;

  TransactionList(this.transactions, this.deleteTx);

  @override
  _TransactionListState createState() => _TransactionListState();
}

class _TransactionListState extends State<TransactionList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 350,
      child: widget.transactions.isEmpty
          ? Column(...
            )
          : ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
                return Dismissible(
                  key: Key(widget.transactions[index].getId()),
                  onDismissed: (direction) {
                    setState(() {
                      widget.deleteTx;
                    });
                    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                      SnackBar(
                          content: Text("${widget.transactions[index].getTitle()} dismissed")),
                    );
                  },
                  background: Container(
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ),
                  child: Card(
                    elevation: 5,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      vertical: 8,
                      horizontal: 5,
                    ),
                    child: ListTile(

    //Formatting the amount entered of the transaction 

                      leading: CircleAvatar(
                        ... ,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),

    //formatting the name/title of the transaction

                      title: Text(
                        ... ,
                      ),

//formatting the date of the transaction
    
                      subtitle: Text(
                        ... ,
                      ),

// adding a delete icon in the transaction card

                      trailing: IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                        color: Theme.of(context).errorColor,
                        onPressed: () =>
                            widget.deleteTx(widget.transactions[index].getId()),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
              itemCount: widget.transactions.length,
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

deletetx is just a function in my main.dart file which is deleting the transaction and changing the state.

```
void _deleteTransaction(String id) {
    setState(() {
      _userTrx.removeWhere((element) {
        return element.getId() == id;
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed `onDismissed()` in the above code snippet to:

```
onDismissed: (direction) => widget.deleteTx( widget.transactions[index].getId() ),
```

and it worked for me.

Comment: You should mark it as answered, so others can find findnit easier.